# Interceptors don't appear to be initializing

Tags: angular

From everything I can see, I have two Interceptors that appear to not even be initialized. Otherwise I would see the console.logs written. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here...HELP!!!!

// token.interceptor.ts
// this should be adding the token as a param to every request...

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { StorageService } from '../storage.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    token: string;

    constructor(
        private storageService: StorageService
    ) {
        console.log('token interceptor initialized');
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log(this.storageService.tokenString);
        if (this.storageService.tokenString) {

            const addToken = req.clone({
                setParams: {
                    token: this.storageService.tokenString
                }
            });

            return next.handle(addToken);
        } else {
            return next.handle(req);
        }
    }

}
```

// authentication.interceptor.ts
// this should be redirecting to the login for 401 errors.

```
import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) {
        console.log('auth interceptor initialized');
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (event.status === 401) {
                            this.router.navigate(['app-login']);
                        }
                    }
                    return throwError(event);
                }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

// and then they are provided in the main app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AuthGuard } from './gaurds/auth.guard';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { AdminGuard } from './gaurds/admin.guard';
import { ManagerGuard } from './gaurds/manager.guard';
import { StorageService } from './storage.service';
import { AuthenticationInterceptor } from './http/authentication.interceptor';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './http/token.interceptor';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        SharedModule,
        CoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        AdminGuard,
        ManagerGuard,
        StorageService,
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: TokenInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor,
            multi: true
        },
        /* {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ResponseInterceptor,
            multi: true
        } */
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I first started having issues with this, because I could see the token.interceptor.ts was not adding the token param to the requests, so I threw in the console logs to start debugging. After seeing this was not getting initialized, i tested the same in the second interceptor and found it is not being initialized either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. could you please use https://stackblitz.com to reproduce the error ?

Comment: might be you have an error somewhere? have you tried just build it your code?